# converting binary input with javascript

Tags: javascript, binary

Im at doing IEE754 --> dec and back converter at this moment and got myself a problem with exponent conversation.

basic idea is to convert all 3 parts  separately and then calculate them all with (-1)^(SIGN) * 1.MANTISSA * 2^(EXPONENT-127). All 3 are inputted separately, so i dont need to divide the binary to parts.

```
function fl2dec(){
    var etuliite = document.getElementById('etu').value;

    var mant = document.getElementById('man').value;

    for (i=0;i>-24;i--)
    {
        //This part is the problem. i would like to do it something like  man = man+(0 or 1)x2^i;
    }
        var binn = document.getElementById('eks').value;
        var decn = parseInt(binn,2);

    //and here is the math part.

    }
    </script>

    <div style="text-align:center">
   <input type="text" id="etu"></input>
     <input type="text" id="eks"></input>
   <input type="text" id="man"></input>
 <button onclick="fl2dec;">IEEE 754 -> Dec</button>
  <input type="text" id="ulos"></input>
  <br />
</div>
```

or if you have otherkind of ideas how to do this, im open for all kind of ideas.

Thank you if you have time to answer my noobish question.

Answer (score 0):

This post only shows some methods of how to perform the operations in Javascript; it does not attempt to actually solve the problem. Take or leave as appropriate.

---

"0 or 1" can be expressed using the ternary expression: `expr ? when_true : when_false`, where `when_true` is 1 and `when_false` is 0 (or reversed), as demonstrated below.

"2^i" can be expressed as `1 << i` or by `Math.pow(2, i)`

So ... `man = man + (should_be_one ? 1 : 0) * x * (1 << i)`

Happy coding